# What is the way to load a fixed number of UICollectionViewCells without reuseIdentifier ? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reuseidentifier

I have 5 columns in `UICollectionView` (horizontal scroll) and everything is working fine.

Every `UICollectionViewCell` contains its own `UITableView` inside and sometimes there is a lot of data in it, so the `UICollectionView` **scroll is not so smooth**.

I realized that the main problem is reusing the cell since the problem occurs only when the table contains a lot of data (10+ rows). Since the data is not updated so often and there is really no need to reuse it while scrolling, I believe that this will fix the 'smooth scroll' problem.

One of the solutions could be to add pagination to `UITableView`, so I can keep `reuseIdentifier` and not think about memory, but I just wanted to check this way as well.

Currently, I'm using this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell {
        // Cell configuration code
        return cell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

I tried with something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = UICollectionViewCell() as? MyCustomCell {
        // Cell configuration code
        return cell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

but every time when I remove reuseIdentifier it's giving me this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'
```

Comment: define them on storyboard by selecting static cells.

Comment: Reuse is the way Apple designed UIColllectionView to work.

Comment: Use a UIStackView, and define your "cells" as UIView and not UICollectionViewCells

Comment: I'd recommend to keep the reuse, that's an important optimization from iOS SDK. Maybe you are doing something wrong or that can be more optimized. But without knowing what you really do, that's quite hard. Are you sure it's not the setting of the cells that are causing the issue?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend keeping with cell reuse. iOS is an embedded system with limited resources, especially memory. If scrolling is not smooth, you may have greater inefficiencies that should be the target of your efforts. Use the Instruments app to measure and investigate what is causing your scrolling to be poor. Once you've solve all of those problems, exploring options such as avoiding cell reuse can be explored.

Comment: Even though the code is 'cleaner' with UICollectionView, I decided to replace UICollectionView with UIScrollView and added five subviews in UIStackView. This solved the problem. I appreciate your advice, I was not so happy with the idea to remove cell reuse as well.